# How to set Django allowed_hosts?

Tags: django

Just don’t understand, in Django documents and other articles, allowed_hosts is not recommended to be [‘*’] for security reasons. But a website should be open to the whole internet, what value should it be?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> But a website should be open to the whole internet

`ALLOWED_HOSTS` in Django settings does not mean who will be allowed to access your site. It simple means on which address your site will be accessible. for example `www.google.com` is the address of google site. That does not mean who will be allowed to access the site (Its already public).

To allow/disallow a particular user to access your site is usually done with firewall or with a proxy server like `nginx`.

> what value should it be?

It simply mentions the list of address from where your site can be accessed. like `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['your_site.com', 'IP_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_SITE']` for more information visit [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)

And for why `['*']` being dangerous and why `ALLOWED_HOST` was added to django please refer to [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45687/what-does-djangos-allowed-hosts-variable-actually-do) post.

Answer (score 1):

It should be set to your application domain. For example, if your domain is http://example.com then you need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS to:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.com']
```